# What is a quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_m^*/\langle p\rangle$?

Tags: quotient-group

Ho can I obtain $\mathbb{Z}_m^{*}/\langle p\rangle$?

Where $\mathbb{Z}_m^{*}$ is multiplicative group, i.e. if $m=8$, $\mathbb{Z}_m^{*}=\{1,3,5,7\}$.
If $p =17$, what is $\mathbb{Z}_8^{*}/\langle 17\rangle$?

Comment: Well in this case $17=1$ so it's obvious. But sometimes $p$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{m}$, eg $m=6$, $p=2$.